# How do I create a certificate with subject containing Octet string?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, x.509

I need to create a certificate with:

```
subject.attribute1: 2.5.4.3 {Common Name} UTF8String
subject.attribute2: 2.5.4.92 {tagAFI} OCTET STRING
subject.attribute3: 0.9.2342.1920.0300.100.1.1 {userId} UTF8String
```

Anyone any idea on how to do this?  OpenSSL doesn't allow me

Comment: I'd have thought you'd need to code this yourself.  Most tools which manipulate X.509 certificates (OpenSSL etc.) are aligned with RFC 5280 which is the _Internet_ profile and a subset of the full X.5** series.  Your `tagAFI` is ISO environment only (as stated in X.520).  I hope I'm wrong...